# Preferred method of adding records to custom tables in Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I've just finished creating a custom surface controller that sends out emails after a user has filled in details of a contact form.

However I'm trying to now store these records in a custom table but I'm not sure what available methods I have of doing this? In previous versions of Umbraco ie. < 4.8 I'd create Linq 2 Sql classes and then save my records using the DataContext object.

Now that Umbraco 6 has moved to MVC I'm a little unsure how I should proceed. I've been looking into using Entity Framework to add my custom records but now I've just seen [this](http://www.enkelmedia.se/blogg/2013/1/24/the-new-data-layer-in-umbraco-6.aspx) article and I wonder if there's another simpler way of adding these new records to my database?

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction here? What is the optimal way of adding records to custom tables in umbraco 6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two answers to this question:

1. Use a framework/solution like EF;
2. Use Contour

If you haven't looked at it, Contour is an Umbraco plugin that does exactly what you need. See here for [more information about Contour](http://umbraco.com/products/more-add-ons/contour.aspx).

However, for more control I use PetaPoco or more recently NPoco (via NuGet) and also Autofac to inject the Database (analogous to DataContext) into the constructor of my Controllers.

This is super easy and if you aren't already using an IoC container like Autofac in your builds I would highly recommend looking into it. Especially if you stick with EF, as you could ensure that a single DataContext object was created and disposed for each request, making sure that you didn't have multiple contexts floating about.

Comment: Thanks Dibgy - seems you're my go-to guy for Umbraco questions haha